# Forward and delete all e-mails using sendmail

Tags: amazon-ec2, sendmail

I'm using Amazon EC2 instances with a preinstalled sendmail for some application testing.

As this is a testing system which might send some e-mail I want to delete and in the same moment forward all outgoing mails to one specific e-mail-address. So I can test different actions which send external mail, but they should get redirected to my fixed static mail, so no mail gets accidentaly send to an external recipient.

I've read about nullclient and mailertable, but these seem only to redirect to a specific smtp server. Isn't it possible to redirect to a specific mail-address? I've already done similar using MercuryMail on windows, but couldn't find a good solution for sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this solution, but it seems to fit your requirement.

http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/sendmailredirectallmailfordevelopment

The second example is the one to use.

```
LOCAL_RULE_0
R$*    $#smtp $@example.com $:someone
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately that leads to no mails send at all without any visible error message :(

Answer (score 0):

You may cactch all outgoing (non local) email using mailertable entry, see `FEATURE(mailertable)`

mailertable:

```
. local:catch-all
```

alaises:

```
catch-all: userx
```

P.S.
You may use `SMART_HOST` instead of mailertable,

Comment: Does that also work by redirecting it to an external e-mail-address?

Comment: You may use `.   esmtp:user@example.net`